# Как заполнить построчно таблицу в Excel с помощью Python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Основная суть вопроса: как занести несколько Dataframe в одну таблицу excel?
Программа берёт файл index.html и парсит его. При выводе в excel таблицу, значения переменной df записываются в одну строчку. Не получается сделать так, чтобы записывалась по-порядку 1 файл = 1 строка в excel. Данные после парсинга (переменной df) выглядят примерно так и они же заносятся в xlsx таблицу:

```
Show   id  detect
0      2   usbhub
0      2   wireless
```

Кто-нибудь знает возможно ли реализовать по строчное заполненине таблицы excel? Одна таблица равно 1 строка в excel. Кто знает, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Если что не понятно, пишите

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import os
from array import *
import openpyxl as ox

dir_viewer = os.listdir("/home/html/") 
#print(dir_viewer)
for onedir in dir_viewer:
#Открывает файл для парсинга
    cur_path = "/home/html/"+str(onedir)+"/index.html"
    if os.path.exists(cur_path):
        with open(cur_path) as fp:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
            fp = pd.read_html(cur_path, match="Detect") 
            for record in fp:
                #print(record)
                #print('==================')   
                df = pd.DataFrame(fp)   
export_csv = df.to_excel(r'program_lang.xlsx', index=None, header=None)
```

Comment: Приведите пример изначальных данных и что Вы хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: @ДимаВиноградов [скрины](https://imgur.com/a/UcARENV) Прошу процения за долгий ответ. В ссылке первый скрин, то что поступает в парсер, на втором - то, что происходит после обработки парсером(таблица), третий скрин, полученное во втором скрине, заносит в таблицу, которую я хочу получить на выводе в xlsx формате. Но мой код почему-то закидывает вывод в одну строчку, перезаписывая предыдущий вывод.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем проблема решилась, добавлением строчек:

```
for_table=[]
for_table.append([onedir,fp])
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import os
from array import *

dir_viewer = os.listdir("/home/html/") 
for_table = []
for onedir in dir_viewer:
#Открывает файл для парсинга
    cur_path = "/home/html/"+str(onedir)+"/index.html"
    if os.path.exists(cur_path):
        with open(cur_path) as fp:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
            fp = pd.read_html(cur_path, match="Defect ID")
            for record in fp:
                print(record)
                print('==================')
                for_table.append([onedir,fp]) #onedir будет первым столбцом в экселе, fp вторым

export_csv = DataFrame(for_table).to_excel(r'program_lang.xlsx', index=None, header=None)
```

Всем спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно Вы сможете адаптировать мою рабочую функцию под свои нужды.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl as oxl

# пример словарь python
data = {"Company":"sony","Website":"sony.com","Country":"japan" }

def write_data():
 try:
    excel = pd.read_excel(r"E:\program_lang.xlsx", index_col=0)#открываем файл
    row = len(excel.index) + 2# ищем пустую ячейку в файле
    wb = oxl.load_workbook(r"E:\program_lang.xlsx")# загружаем существующий excel
    sheet = wb.active
    columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','N']# пишем нужные колонки excel для записи
    col = 0
    for k in data:
        sheet[columns[col] + str(row)] = str(data[k])
        col = col + 1
    wb.save(r"E:\program_lang.xlsx")
  except PermissionError:
    print('--- Oшибка! Вы забыли закрыть excel фаил ---' )
```